# How to access the rendered screen pixels and manipulate them in unity? (3 gifs)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm making a bullet hell shooter, and need to add effects of different types, and I wish I can access the screen pixels so I manipulate them, I have been able to do unique effects in texture 2D by shifting pixels and replacing them, but the camera pixels them selfs are not editable,

type 1-
[image: effect2]
[image: effect1]
[image: effect3]

type 2-
and being able to draw on screen lines between objects
like this but in game not in editor, and make the lines zig zag, squiglly or dashed etc...
[image: lines]

any hints ?

Comment: Might be a little overkill but you may want to look in to [shaders](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/gentle-introduction-shaders).

Comment: that will not be supported on old android tablet, i don't want to do something demanding on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, pixels that are being rendered in camera are read only, what you can do is the following.

0) Create a RenderTexture in your assets with Create>RenderTexture.

1) Render from a camera to a RenderTexture, for this go to the camera that is currently viewing what you want to edit, and chose your RenderTexture as the Target Texture.

2) You can't edit a RenderedTexture directly during runtime, but you can read it and copy it as a new Texture2D, from here you can edit the Texture2D as you normally would.

3) Add the newly created/updated Texture2D to a gameObject on your scene and view it from a camera (Normally i use the main camera for this purpose, on a new layer).

Here is the official unity manual for the related terms,

Render Texture:

> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html

Camera manual (Includes Target Texture):

> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html

Comment: i made this already, but it requires a lot of processing for 640*480 res on mobile, so it's not fast :(

Comment: Yes, definately editing pixels via script is a heavy and unoptimal task compared to shaders, although i've managed to make it work efficiently with a couple of tweaks, such as using power of two squared textures or using texture2d.apply() only at the end of each frame.

Comment: there are no square screens, like if i want to use a 512*512 res, do you have sample code though? and what do you think of shaders as a solution?

Comment: Shaders are limited to some extent, I've not yet seen them DIRECTLY drawing lines on screen and other objects, thats more of a job for textures. But whenever you can achieve something using Shaders, then you should use them.
It is true that you don't have squared screens, but there you have to get a little bit creative, for example, on a 640*480 you can use a 5 by 4 matrix of 128*128 textures, you will get a 640*512, but even then it's more efficient than a single 640*480.
Another thing is to track where on screen the lines must be drawn, and create multiple transparent textures locally.

Comment: I'm still not fully clear on what is it that you want to achieve, so its hard to provide code, i'd even recommend you creating a particle system at this point. Or another thing that comes to mind is a LineRenderer component.